# How to set up a QVariantAnimation for put forward QWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have this code to switch between the menu

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsEffect, QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QLabel


'''
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QPoint
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QGraphicsEffect, QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
'''

class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        center_lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        center_lay.setObjectName(u"center_lay")
        Spacer_1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(17, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        center_lay.addItem(Spacer_1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        Spacer_2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(327, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        center_lay.addItem(Spacer_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        Spacer_3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(326, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        center_lay.addItem(Spacer_3, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        Spacer_4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        center_lay.addItem(Spacer_4, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        block.setObjectName(u"block")
        center_lay.addWidget(block, 1, 1, 1, 1)         
        block.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 300))
        lay_block = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(block)
        lay_block.setObjectName(u"lay_block")
        block.setStyleSheet('''background:#000''')
        self.mv_blur_but = QtWidgets.QWidget(block)
        self.mv_blur_but.setObjectName(u"mv_blur_but")
        self.mv_blur_but.setGeometry(QRect(110, 20, 111, 111))  
        self.mv_blur_but.setStyleSheet('''background:#fff''')   
        move_blur_button_lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.mv_blur_but)
        move_blur_button_lay.setObjectName(u"move_blur_button_lay")
        self.mv_rad_arr = []
        self.mv_cont_arr = []   
        for x in range(2):
            radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.mv_blur_but)
            radio.setObjectName("mv_radio_but-{}".format(x))
            radio.pressed.connect(self.off)
            radio.toggled.connect(self.anim )
            self.mv_rad_arr.append(radio)
            move_blur_button_lay.addWidget(self.mv_rad_arr[x])
            mv_blur_menu = QtWidgets.QWidget(block)
            mv_blur_menu.resize(50, 60)
            mv_blur_menu.move(60 , 20)
            self.mv_cont_arr.append(mv_blur_menu)
            but = self.mv_rad_arr[x]
            menu = self.mv_cont_arr[x]
        self.mv_cont_arr[0].setStyleSheet('''background:#ff0''')
        self.mv_cont_arr[1].setStyleSheet('''background:#f0f''')
        self.radio_1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.mv_blur_but)
        self.radio_1.setObjectName("mv_radio_but-99")
        self.radio_1.move(-self.radio_1.width(),0)
        self.mv_rad_arr.append(self.radio_1)
        self.group = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(self) 
        self.num = 0
        self.menu_group_ani = []
    def anim (self):
        self.animation= []
        for i in range(2):
            menuAnimation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation() #Fun Animation
            menuAnimation.setDuration(500) #Time
            menuAnimation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutQuart)
            menuAnimation.setStartValue(QPoint(-20, 10))
            menuAnimation.setEndValue(QPoint(0, 10))
            self.animation.append(menuAnimation)
        self.num =self.num+1
        old = int(self.sender().objectName().split('-')[1])
        self.menu_group_ani.append(old)
        print(self.menu_group_ani)
        ff_id = 0
        for id in sorted(self.menu_group_ani):
            pos1 = QPoint(60 , 20)
            pos2 = QPoint(221, 20)
            self.animation[ff_id].setStartValue(pos1)
            self.animation[ff_id].setEndValue(pos2)
            self.animation[ff_id].valueChanged.connect(lambda value, val=self.menu_group_ani[ff_id]: self.chengeval(value, val))
            self.mv_cont_arr[self.menu_group_ani[0]].raise_()
            self.mv_blur_but.raise_()
            if self.mv_cont_arr[self.menu_group_ani[ff_id]].pos() == pos2:
                self.animation[ff_id].setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
            else :
                self.animation[ff_id].setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
            ff_id +=1
        try: 
            self.animation[0].finished.connect(self.animation[1].start)
        except IndexError:
            print('Err')
        if (self.num == 1) or (self.num == 3):
            self.menu_group_ani.clear()
            self.animation[0].start()
        if self.num == 3 :
            self.num = 1    
    def off(self):
        check_1 = self.sender().isChecked()
        if check_1 == True:
            print('check')
            self.radio_1.setChecked(True)    #Unchecked/Checked
            self.menu_group_ani.clear()
        else:
            print('uncheked')
    def chengeval(self,value,val=''):
        self.mv_cont_arr[val].move(value.x(), value.y())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()
    win.resize(640, 570)  
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

everything works well until i turn it on off(self)
why is the code so unstable?

problem

[image]

I need

[image]

I tried to work on self.menu_group_ani using  clear() or if 
but whatever I do the code is not working correctly
clicked.connect also did not give the desired result
How to fix it?

Comment: 1) Verify your code as it generates errors. 2) Eliminate unnecessary imports such as `from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine` as they distract. 3) Not only place images but explain where the error is. 4) What is the specific objective of this code?

Comment: @eyllanesc the error is that during the functions off() radio does not switch to self.radio_1, which is why when I switch from self.mv_rad_arr[0] to self.mv_rad_arr[1] an error occurs. It is necessary either to clear somehow self.menu_group_ani before running or to force off() switch to self.radio_1.